# Complexity of the min-max algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have the following code. What recurrence relation should hold for it and what will be its complexity. It will be really nice if you can help me find its complexity by solving the recurrence relation using substitution method.

Node variable to store multiple return values

```
struct node
{
    int MAXX;
    int MINN;
}NODE;
```

Recursive function that finds the minimum and maximum numbers from a given array

```
struct node partition(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int MAX, MIN;
    int low = first;
    int high = last;
    struct node left, right;

    /*If there is a single variable */
    if (low==high)
    {
        NODE.MAXX = a[low];
        NODE.MINN = a[low];
        return(NODE);
    }
    /*If there exists only 2 elements*/
    else if (high==low+1)
    {
        if (a[high]>a[low])
        {
            NODE.MAXX = a[high];
            NODE.MINN = a[low];
        }
        else
        {
            NODE.MAXX = a[low];
            NODE.MINN = a[high];
        }
        return NODE;
    }
    /*If there exists more than 2 elements */
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    left=partition(a, low, mid);
    right=partition(a, mid+1, high);
    if (left.MAXX > right.MAXX)
        NODE.MAXX = left.MAXX;
    else
        NODE.MAXX = right.MAXX;
    if (left.MINN < right.MINN)
        NODE.MINN = left.MINN;
    else
        NODE.MINN = right.MINN;

    return NODE;

}
```

Main function

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct node N;
    int a[] = { 70, 50, 111, 69, 4, 7, 80, 100 }; 
    N=partition(a, 0, 7);
    cout << "Maximum = " << N.MAXX << endl;
    cout << "Minimum = " << N.MINN << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `partition` performs a constant amount of work, plus 2 additional recursive calls, each with *half* of the input index range. We can thus construct a *recurrence relation* for the time complexity function:

`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C`

This expands to a geometric series `C * (1 + 2 + 4 + ... )`, which continues for `log n` terms (because at each level of recursion the input size halves, so it decreases geometrically to the stopping condition `n = 2`). From standard formulae, this equates to `O(n)`.

---

EDIT: equations to improve on the previous explanation:

[image]

Comment: Could you please expand the above said formula and prove it to be O(n)?

Comment: I think each time C will be added...kindly check it....For kth step it should be Ck.

Comment: @Navdeep Nope. Each call does work proportional to C, but there are 2 recursive calls per call, which means that the number of C added grows exponentially, hence the geometric series.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain it a bit more..I have understood everything very clearly except this. Thanks.

Comment: @Navdeep I don't know how I can explain more clearly than I already have, but let's try walking through this step by step. In the first call you do work C, and call recursively twice. Those two calls each do work C and each also call twice, giving 4 additional calls and additional work 2C. The next 4 calls do work 4C and make 8 additional calls, and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151825/discussion-between-navdeep-and-meowgoesthedog).